# RPSCommonObjects.m Parse Issue Unknown Type Name NSString

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform, xcode6

I am trying to integrate a Facebook Login into a simple tab bar controller app. I followed the steps to set up my enviornment with Parse and the Facebook SDK. After I run the application a unrelated file that looks like this :

```
NSString *builtInOpenGraphObjects[3] = {
                                    @"672839339475385",      // rock
                                    @"296430467206197",      // paper
                                    @"524651207660361"};     // scissors
```

Shows up and gives me an error

```
Unknown type name 'NSString'
```

I have my bridging header as I am using swift to complete this project. I imported my Parse and Facebook files. When I tried to comment this file out it caused a lot more errors. So far this is the only reason my app will not build.

I am also using XCode 6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hey everyone who may come across this issue I have figured out the problem. I dragged the entire FacebookSDK folder as shown in tutorials on Facebooks developers page. **You do not need to do that in fact you should not have your frameworks within other folders inside the main frameworks folder.**

1. Parse SDK should already have bolts framework that Facebook SDK supplies so delete that.
2. Next, drag out other Frameworks that were not included in Parse or your iOS8 frameworks to the Frameworks folder.
3. Delete the FaceBookSDK Folder.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. I dragged the FacebookSDK folder into my project.

Found the problem occurred in the Samples Folder. Deleted that and my project ran successfully.
Using Xcode 6 Beta